# How do I maintain API versions?

Tags: 8

I have different REST End points in my Drupal 8 instance, some of them are exposed from REST Views and some are custom controllers. I have a situation where I want to maintain versioning with my end points.
I have replaced some fields in the new version and the users relying on the older API version must not be impacted by the change.
In the case of a controller, how can I manage different output for different API versions?
Also, in the case of REST Views, where the URL is directly exposed, how can new data be added to that?

For example, the */rest/taxonomy-list* endpoint gives a certain set of terms as JSON output. In the new API version, I have to add/remove/replace one term which is present in same vocabulary.

Comment: In the case of a controller, you use the version number as part of the URL, for example /api/2/rest-endpoint-name and /api/3/rest-endpoint-name.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, change in URL can be done, but if I have a minor change in the output, do I have to create a new method for it?

Comment: I would use the new URL for the new versions, and leave the old URL for legacy. I would not create a different route for a minor change. To me, /api/3/rest-endpoint-name is totally different from /api/2/rest-endpoint-name, at the point that trying use the output of /api/3/rest-endpoint-name as it were the output of /api/2/rest-endpoint-name, I would get totally wrong results.

Comment: Consider my example for an instance where I'm listing all terms of vocabulary in v1 and I want 10 newly added terms only in v2. Can that be managed from Drupal?

Answer (score 2):

One approach to version the API is to add a version number to the URL.
So, for example your Views REST display URL `/rest/taxonomy-list` would become `/rest/v1/taxonomy-list` or `/rest/v2/taxonomy-list`

You could [duplicate the existing Views display](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/add-a-display-to-a-view#s-duplicate-displays) to adjust the fields and new URL in a new REST display.

For custom REST API plugins, you can extend the existing RestResource and give it a new URL, e.g:

```
use Drupal\my_module\MyRestResource;

/**
 * Sample Rest Resource
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = “my_rest_resource_v2”,
 *   label = @Translation(“My Rest Resource (v2)“),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/rest/v2/endpoint”
 *   }
 * )
 */
class MyRestResourceV2 extends MyRestResource {

  // Extend and override functions here 

}
```

Comment: It will work in case of Rest Plugins but in case of view URLs?
I don't want to duplicate a view for the change in a single field.